# Setting up and using the UINavigationController class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I am trying to use the UINavigationController class in Objective-C, but I am having a difficult time understanding how it should work.

Basically, I have my app. I want to use the UINavigationController to show a hierarchy of data stored in an NSArray. I currently have this data being presented in UITableView. I want to make it so a user can click on a row of the table view and be taken to more specific data about the row they just clicked. I think a UINavigationController is perfect for this.

However, my understanding of MVC in the context of  Objective-C is not that good and I am confused about how to do this. I want the UINavigationController to only show up in the left half of my iPad app and I would also like the ability to hide it at times. So how do I configure this?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the correct usage for a navigation controller.

What you will need to do is create your navigation controller and populate the root view with your view controller containing the table view. In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath you would push the detail view onto the stack. All the navigation will be set up to go back for you.

Most likely in your AppDelegate:

```
ListViewController *theView = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theView];
[theView release];
[window addSubview:navView.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```